# CRM Analytics for Community Logins/Members

Tags: permission-sets, experience-cloud, crm-analytics

I have an Experience Cloud Site and am trying to display a *CRM Analytics Dashboard* to a user with a **Partner Community** license.

I have created the Dashboard, and shared it's App with **Partner Community Users** as *Viewer*[image: Share Dasbhard]

Next I go to add a Permission Set License to my Partner Community user, I have two Permission Set Licenses:

- CRM Analytics for Community Logins
- CRM Analytics for Community Members

[image: CRM Analytics for Community Permission Set License]

First - what is the difference between these two licenses?

Second - Even when assigning these Permission Set Licenses to a Partner Community user, and embedding the dashboard in a Lightning Component for my Experience Cloud, the **user does not see the dashboard**

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

In our organization we use the PSL "CRM Analytics for Community Members" to provide access of the embedded CRMA Dashboards to the Partner Community license users.
You have followed all the necessary steps i believe but haven't really mentioned the assigning of Permission Set to the desired users with the permissions "View CRM Analytics on Experience Cloud site pages" enabled? So I think that might be the missing piece. Just assigning the PSL to the user doesn't do the trick.